# How do I align text that is in the body of other text?

Tags: microsoft-word

[I'm not allowed to embed images because of my low level: the image is this link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsXBc.png)

I want to align all the output text, so it starts on the same line. Is there a way to do this? I did google, but I'm having a hard time searching when I don't know how to explain what I want done.

Comment: Probably not what you hoped, but if you want to align text in that way, probably best to start with a two-column table where you use the rows in the table to achieve the vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Place a tab before each instance of "Output", then select all the lines and in the tab ruler move the tab symbol to the desired location.

For convenience, you can:

- Save a style with these settings
- Use the format painter to copy/paste the settings
- Cntrl+Shift+C will put the format in a special clipboard and Cntrl+Shift+V will paste it.